# How to access a specific bit given a byte in C?

Tags: c, binary, byte, bit

For example,suppose I have something like "0000 0000 0000 1110".

How can I access the left most 1 and change it to 0?

Comment: In general, for bit-twiddling hacks like this, consult [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This two functions can handle 64 bit value.

```
uint8_t get_bit(uint64_t bits, uint8_t pos)
{
   return (bits >> pos) & 0x01;
}

uint64_t set_bit(uint64_t bits, uint8_t pos, uint8_t value)
{
   uint64_t mask = 1LL << (63 - pos);
   if (value)
       bits |= mask;
   else
       bits &= ~mask;
   return bits;
}

uint64_t v = ...;
uint8_t i = 63;
for(;i>=0; i--)
{
    if(get_bit(v, i)){
       v=set_bit(v,i, 0);
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: One-liner to get the msb that is set to 1: `i = floor(log(bits)/log(2))`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for **[bit masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29)**

For example:

```
00011001 >> 3 = 00000011
```

Now mask it with 1

```
00000011 & 00000001 = 00000001
```

Code:-

```
int funcBitMasking(int8_t mybyte, int firstbit)
{
    if (firstbit> 0 && firstbit<= 16)
        return (mybyte & (1<<(firstbit-1)));
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bitwise And (&) . like 0000 0000 0000 1110 & 0000 0000 0000 1000 will give non zero answer

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your input is 32 bits.  We scan the input for the first 1, left shifting; change the first bit to 0 by `&`ing it with `0X7FFF` and right shift by the number we left shifted + 1.

```
unsigned int i = 0XE;
int j;

for ( j = 0; j < 32 && ! ( i & 0X8000 ); j++ )
    i <<= 1;

i &= 0X7FFF;
i >>= ( j + 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose a = 0000 0000 0000 1110

```
int i =16 ;
 b = 1;
while(true)
{

  b = b << 1 ;
  if(b & 0x1000000000000000)
  {
   break;
  }
 i = i +1 ;
}
```

and you will have acces toyour bit like  this

```
int yourbit= ~0; /* All 1’s */ 
youtbit = (max >> (i+1) ) +  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mentioning the fourth bit from the right hand side as the left most bit.

For accessing a specific bit, you can use `Shift Operators`.

If it is always a `1` that you are going to reset, then you could use an `&` operation.

But, if it can also take `0` value, then `&` operation will fail as `0 & 1 = 0`. You could use `| (OR)` during that time.

Store this value in a variable and make an `OR` operation with `(1 << 4)`
The right hand side of the Shift operator, will take the position of the bit from right-side. And, left-hand side of the Shift operator, will take the value to be placed on that position. The operator points to the direction, the value has to be shifted.

Please refer the following links, for more information.

http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4ab.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2247/An-introduction-to-bitwise-operators

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int mlb_pos(uint16_t x) {//0 origin
    uint16_t y;
    int n = 16;
    y = x >>  8; if (y != 0){ n = n -  8 ; x = y; }
    y = x >>  4; if (y != 0){ n = n -  4 ; x = y; }
    y = x >>  2; if (y != 0){ n = n -  2 ; x = y; }
    y = x >>  1; if (y != 0){ return 15-(n-2); }
    return 15-(n-x);
}

int main(){
    uint16_t n = 14;//0b0000000000001110
    uint16_t result = n ^ (1<<mlb_pos(n));
    printf("%d\n", result);//6 : 0b0000000000000110
}
```